# OnClickListener priority?

Tags: android

Layout XML code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/item_noti_follow_wrapper_ll">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_noti_follow_name_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="TextViewHereThere"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

And Here is java code:

```
LinearLayoutCompat lc = findViewById(R.id.item_noti_follow_wrapper_ll);
lc.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener {
// Here Some layout Code
})

TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.item_noti_follow_name_tv);
tv.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener{
// here for textview code
})
```

In this case, if I click TextView tv, I guessed both layout code and textview code would be working.

But just textview code worked.

What's the reason of this situation?

Is there any priority of OnClickListener with layout tree?

Comment: One possible answer may be the height of the view may overtake it hence why the linear layout doesn't get it possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one click listener will work at a time. The deepest child will get the priority over it's parents:

XML:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_noti_follow_wrapper_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_noti_follow_name_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:duplicateParentState="true"
                    android:text="Click here"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Activity: (in Kotlin)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        item_noti_follow_wrapper_ll.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Click", "LinearLayout")
        }

        item_noti_follow_name_tv.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Click", "TextView")
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking on the text then to the right of the text yields these logs:

> 2020-01-02 14:42:33.953 28019-28019/com.example.test D/Click: TextView
>   2020-01-02 14:42:35.678 28019-28019/com.example.test D/Click:
>   LinearLayout

As you can see both click listeners work and the child takes priority.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `android:clickable=true` for the layout as it, by default does not react to clicks.

Answer (score 1):

On click listeners prioritizes the inner-most child/children within a view group. So if your LinearLayout is clickable along with its child, the child view gets the priority.

The priority follows the hierarchy from the inner-most views to the parent (the parent being the least priority)